# Картинка поверх картинки HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер!

Есть доска объявлений, где идет общий список объявлений строками. Если включаешь функцию «VIP объявление», строка окрашивается в другой цвет. Пытаюсь прикрутить картинку «VIP» уголком поверх изображения объявления. Однако `div` имеет переменные, которые определяют, какое объявление — простое или VIP, и применяют  разные стили CSS. Как прикрутить картинку поверх в таком случае?

```
<td valign="top" width="{$colwidth}%">
  <div class="bd_item{if $con.is_vip}_vip{/if}">
```

**переменные, отвечающие за простое или VIP объявление**

```
<table width="100%" height="" cellspacing="" cellpadding="0" class="b_table_tr">
  <tr>
    {if $cfg.photos}
      <td width="90" valign="top">
        <img class="bd_image_small" src="/images/board/small/{$con.file}" border="0" alt="{$con.title|escape:'html'}"/>
      </td>
```

Comment: не понял структуру таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере недостаточно информации по структуре, но я рискну выложить реализацию. [Демо](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOjOPY).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML

```
<div class="bd_item bd_item_vip">
   <img src="/path/to/image">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bd_item {
   position: relative;
   width: 140px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.bd_item_vip:after {
    content: 'VIP';
    background: #C76649;
    z-index: 800;
    padding-top: 3px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 14px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center center;
    transform-origin: center center;
    top: 3px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #7A3521;
    right: -38px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
}
```